# Rails find over multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find

I think I'm missing something very obvious and its making my brain hurt.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :profile

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :user
belongs_to :team
```

I have a partial that loops through the users and print some basic info, I'm using this partial in my team show page.

I had originally written this to return users who's profiles were a member of a team.

```
def show
@team = Team.find_by_id(params[:id])
@profiles= Profile.find(:all, :conditions => ['team_id = ?', @team.id])
@users = User.find_by_id(@profiles.user_id)
end
```

But quickly realized @profiles was an array, and it looks messy as hell. Stuck as to what my find should look like to select all User who have a profile that is a member of a team.

The partial that is working elsewhere for displaying users looks like this

```
<% for user in @users%>
<table>
<tr>
        <td>
        <%= image_tag user.profile.picture.url %>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a href="/users/<%= user.id %>"><%= user.login %></a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <%= user.profile.first_name %> <%= user.profile.second_name %>
        </td>
        <td>
        <%= user.profile.status %>
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

Development log output with updated show and relationships

```
Processing TeamsController#show (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-03-30 22:06:31) [GET]
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (1.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 3) LIMIT 1
  Team Load (1.0ms)   SELECT * FROM "teams" WHERE ("teams"."id" = 1) 
Rendering template within layouts/main
Rendering teams/show
Completed in 75ms (View: 11, DB: 2) | 200 OK [http://localhost/teams/1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would change your associations to something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :profile

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :team

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :profiles
has_many :users, :through => :profiles
```

I think the problem you are having is that in a has_one relationship one has to be the owner and one has to be the ownee.. (belongs_to)

Then you should be able to find associations using the following:

```
@user.profile
@team.users
@team.profiles
```

etc..

If you want the user to have a profile and the team to display its user's profiles you would change the models to this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :profile
belongs_to :team

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :users
has_many :profiles, :through => :users
```

This way you could load your team, its users and the users profiles:

```
@team = Team.find(params[:id])
@users = @team.users
@profiles = @team.profiles
```

Good luck!

In order for your associations to work properly with the above code your db tables will need to have the following:

Your profiles table will need to have user_id as an integer.

Your users table will need to have team_id as an integer.

Your teams table doesn't need any ids.

Verify that your migrations setup these id's properly and that when a user is created that it is associated with your team properly:

```
@team.users << @user
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It doesn't appear to be selecting the users correctly, although it seems to make sense when I worked through it on paper. Added log and partial

Comment: KGB Make sure all your associations are set correctly? As long as your users are associated with your team it should work.. I'll add what your table structure should look like.

Comment: Oops I also forgot to add the belongs_to declaration under the User model. That could also cause trouble. :) Post edited to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

Change your association as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :users, :through => :profiles
end
```

Make sure you have `user_id` and `team_id` columns on `profiles` table.

Change your `show` method as follows:

```
def show
  @team   = Team.find(params[:id])
  @profile= @team.profile
  @user   = @profile.user
end
```

**PS:**

Above code will work if a team has one profile and a profile belongs to a team and a user.

Comment: How I'm hoping to work it is that a user has a profile, and a team has many profiles. On the show page for a specific team I'll list all the user with a profile for that team.

Comment: Edited my answer for your purpose kgb. Cheers!